# Convert 1D object numpy array of lists to 2D numeric array and back

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have this object array containing lists of the same length:

```
>>> a = np.empty(2, dtype=object)
>>> a[0] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a[1] = [5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], dtype=object)
```

1. How can I convert this to a numeric 2D array?

   ```
   >>> a.shape
   (2,)
   >>> b = WHAT_GOES_HERE(a)
   >>> b
   array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
          [5, 6, 7, 8]])
   >>> b.shape
   (2, 4)
   ```
2. How can I do the reverse?
3. Does it get easier if my `a` array is an `np.array` of `np.array`s, rather than an `np.array` of `list`s?

   ```
   >>> na = np.empty(2, dtype=object)
   >>> na[0] = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
   >>> na[1] = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])
   >>> na
   array([array([1, 2, 3, 4]), ([5, 6, 7, 8])], dtype=object)
   ```

Comment: @Divakar: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` -  `astype` can't reshape

Answer (score 3):

One approach using [`np.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) -

```
b = np.concatenate(a).reshape(len(a),*np.shape(a[0]))
```

The improvement suggest by `@Eric` to use `*np.shape(a[0])` should make it work for generic `ND` shapes.

Sample run -

```
In [183]: a
Out[183]: array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], dtype=object)

In [184]: a.shape
Out[184]: (2,)

In [185]: b = np.concatenate(a).reshape(len(a),*np.shape(a[0]))

In [186]: b
Out[186]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])

In [187]: b.shape
Out[187]: (2, 4)
```

---

To get back `a`, it seems we can use a two-step process, like so -

```
a_back = np.empty(b.shape[0], dtype=object)
a_back[:] = b.tolist()
```

Sample run -

```
In [190]: a_back = np.empty(b.shape[0], dtype=object)
     ...: a_back[:] = b.tolist()
     ...: 

In [191]: a_back
Out[191]: array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], dtype=object)

In [192]: a_back.shape
Out[192]: (2,)
```

Comment: Nice concise solution for the reverse - I was thinking I might have to resort to a for loop

Comment: Replacing the `-1` with `np.shape(a[0])` makes this work for the more general 1D of ND -> N+1D case too

Comment: @Eric Thanks for the improvement! Updated the post.

Answer (score 2):

You canuse np.vstack():

```
>>> a = np.vstack(a).astype(int)
```

Comment: I think the `astype()` is unecessary too!

Comment: yes, you are right, although you didn't explicitly say you wanted int in the end (although - what esle in this example...), so better leave it in ;)

Comment: I just said numeric, and in this case the dtype is int32 anyway, it seems

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that converts the source NumPy array to lists and then into the desired NumPy array:

```
b = np.array([k for k in a])
b
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
c = np.array([k for k in b], dtype=object)
c
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that round-tripping through `list` with `np.array(list(a))` was sufficient.

This seems to be equivalent to using `np.stack(a)`.

Both of these have the benefit of working in the more general case of converting a 1D array of ND arrays into an (N+1)D array.